# Laravel orderBy with child relationship and parent at the same time

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, sorting, eloquent

I have a list with messages. Its possible to reply to these messages (parent - child). I do not show child-messages in the list.
How can I always display the newest parent-message on top. Newest means that either the parent OR one of the childern has the newest timestamp.

Here is my eloquent query:

```
        Message::withCount(['childMessages as latest_child_message' => function($query) {
            $query->select(DB::raw('max(created_at)'));
        }])
        ->orderByDesc('latest_child_message')
        ->orderByDesc('created_at')
        ->get();
```

Both orderBy should somehow be combined. Otherwise either the parent or the child sort will be prioritised.

In the context it's not possible to sort the collection after the DB-query.

---

edit 1:
Since "ee" is the latest response (child), the "bb" message should be at the bottom of the list.

[image: list of messages and responses]

---

edit 2:
The query will be used in a function returning a query

```
public static function getEloquentQuery(): Builder {
    $query = parent::getEloquentQuery();
    return $query->doTheMagicHere();
}
```

---

edit 3
This would be a working query.. but it's very slow

```
SELECT
    id,
    comment,
    (SELECT MAX(cc.id) FROM comments cc WHERE cc.commentable_id = c.id) AS child_id
FROM
    comments c
WHERE
    commentable_type NOT LIKE '%Comment%'
ORDER BY CASE WHEN child_id IS NULL
              THEN id
              ELSE child_id
              END DESC
    ;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `withCount` closure you must set conditions.

Use this:

```
Message::with('childMessages')->get()->sortByDesc(function ($parent, $key) {
            $child = $parent->childMessages()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();
            return $child ? $child->created_at : $parent->created_at;
        });
```

the orderBy way you need is a bit complicated. it's better to use `sortByDesc` method and sort data on collection.

I hope this works.

Comment: Hi Zohreh
Thanks for your response. I dindn't know one can order relations by the dot notation.

Anyway it doesn't work. When you have two orderBy, since one of them will have priority (either the childMessages or the parent messages). 

I'll add a print-screen to the original question to clarify my point.

Comment: Hi Zohreh. It would be a working answer, but in my case it wont work. My query is part of a bigger query. It is in a callback-function receiving a query and returning the enriched query.